# SharePoint custom filed type

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need some help to show me how to create SharePoint custom field type? does anyone have any resources so I can read.

Regards

Comment: SharePoint version?

Comment: SharePoint version is 2016

Answer (score 0):

You could use use client-side rendering or server-side rendering to create custom field type in SharePoint.

Here is an article for you reference: [How to create custom field type in SharePoint ?](http://sharethepunto.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-create-custom-field-type.html)